# Codeigniter array to object conversation

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am getting this error "Trying to get property of non-object" for lines

```
'price' => $product->product_price,
'name' => $product->product_name
```

for doing in the same page

```
    function remove($rowid) {
  $this->cart->update(array(
        'rowid' => $rowid,
        'qty' => 0
    ));
}
```

i can solve this problem, by doing like, `'price' => $product['product_price'],`Bus as my other page using `'price' => $product->product_price`them as fine, so i dont want to convert it to array,
my question is how can i convert `$this->cart->update(array(` to an object so that, these lines

```
'price' => $product->product_price,
'name' => $product->product_name
```

works fine for object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Arr = array(
        'rowid' => $rowid,
        'qty' => 0
    );
$Obj = (object)$Arr;
```

This is conversion of Array to Object. Do you want it?

Comment: I tried like this, didnt work. 
$data=array(
    'rowid' => $rowid,
    'qty' => 0
);
$obj=(object)$data;
$this->cart->update($obj);

Answer (score 0):

You assign the result to an array. Then you try to use the array as an object. Next, the returned result is an array as well which you try to use as a object.

**The smarter ways you can convert array into object**

**From PHP manual:**

```
<?php
  $literalObjectDeclared = (object) array(
     'foo' => (object) array(
          'bar' => 'baz',
          'pax' => 'vax'
      ),
      'moo' => 'ui'
   );
print $literalObjectDeclared->foo->bar; // outputs "baz"!
?>
```

**little genius hack:**

```
<?php    
// assuming $var is a multidimensional array
$obj = json_decode (json_encode ($var), FALSE);
?>
```

**So you can convert by casting array into object:**

```
<?php    
$array = array(
    // ...
    );
    $object = (object) $array;
?>
```

**if you want manual way you can do this:**

```
<?php    
$object = object;
    foreach($arr as $key => $value)
    {
    $object->{$key} = $value;
    }
?>
```

Comment: I tried like this: but it didn't work.$data=array(
    'rowid' => $rowid,
    'qty' => 0
); $object=object; foreach($data as $key=>$value){ $object->{$key}=$value; $this->cart->update($object);

Comment: I updated the answer, and added a working solution. first test it as it.[run php online](http://phpfiddle.org/) then use it. first learn what it does then implement

Answer (score 0):

Define $product as a new standard class:

```
$product = new stdClass();
```

Comment: what does that mean? what will happen if i do this?
thank you.

Comment: Declare it on top of $product, the error you are getting is a result of calling of an object that doesn't have the product_price property.